# how to download apk from google play using php?

Tags: php, android, google-play

Hey guys i have this project which needs to download APK file directly from google play store to the PC using an PHP script.
I have looked into the python script which is very old and doesn't work now.
I see sites like [apkpure.com](http://www.apkpure.com) and [apk-dl](http://www.apk-dl.com) are doing it.

I have used google play link **scraper** [Link](https://github.com/raulr/google-play-scraper) to **scrape** the application details from google play store.
But i can't figure out a way to get the application itself from google play.
Can anyone guide me in a right direction for this?
Really appreciate it guys.
Thanks.

The link **scraper** that i use only fetches the application information not the application itself.
I also looked into chrome extensions like some of you suggested but they don't hold the answer that i require.
Please suggest something else.

Comment: Post the code that you tried and the issues with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to download apks outside of an android device. However, a team found a way to do it with a Chrome extension, whose source code is available on [Github](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/apk-downloader).

It has also been updated to be available as a website: https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

Maybe you can find a way to reimplement it with php (see [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1809458) for more details) or you can try to "use" the website from php... But I am not sure it is feasible.